# Error while trying to run the Program Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

Every time I create a new project in Visual Studio it gives me this error

> Error while trying to run project:could not load file or assembly '[project_name_here]' one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

I am not able to understand what is the problem with Visual Studio or .NET Framework, today I even tried to re-install the .NET Framework but still I don't get it to work.

It always keeps saying this message, even if I just Start the Build process as soon as Creating the project. This happens even if I create the project of (Empty) Console Application and run it, with just a Main method.

When I create the projects in C++, they run, but when I try to run the projects in C# they give me this error. I have tried almost all the methods provided on Stack Overflow, CodeProject, MSDN forums etc. But, nothing works.

What should I do or write to my application so that it would work.

I have, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate update 2 running on Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 with no extensions or updates, just a pure Visual Studio from Microsoft.

Comment: what version of visual studio?

Comment: does this happen when you do nothing but create an empty console application and run it?

Comment: 2013 update 2 I'm using. @Claptrap

Comment: yes, I create the Empty console aplication with just a main method and run it, it does the same. :( @SamIam

Comment: Ultimate @Claptrap ..

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @PhilipPittle, No extensions at all. Just a pure Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 update 2 from Microsoft.

Comment: Try running in safe mode and see if you still have the issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx

Comment: you can try to reset your visual studio by starting it with the command line switch /setup

Comment: @Claptrap I have tried a Reset by the Installer, it doesn't fix it.